# DataStax Enterprise: No search results from Solr

Tags: solr, datastax-enterprise, datastax

I’m using DataStax 3.2.7 and have 2 rows in Cassandra that show up in cqlsh.

I cannot find these records in Solr, though, even after reloading the core and fully reindexing.

Any suggestions?

I also see this in the log: Type mapping versions older than 2 are unsupported for CQL3 table linkcurrent_search.content_items,​ forcing version 2.

Comment: Please provide more information about your cql/solr schema, solr config, and query.

Comment: Hi, can you share the types you are using and your solr config? Have you changed the dseTypeMappingVersion element in your solrconfig?

Comment: Are other records coming back?

Comment: No records are coming back, the query is for any records. What do you mean by types that I'm using? Is that the Cassandra schema? Last but not least, I have no idea about why I should change dseTypeMappingVersion. P.S. Will attach the files in a moment.

Comment: Here's the gist with all the files https://gist.github.com/wagerlabs/1c43da737553e6c97eec

Comment: <!-- Enable DSE Search new type mappings -->
  <dseTypeMappingVersion>1</dseTypeMappingVersion>

Comment: The setup that works is 3.2.5 and mine is 3.2.7. I'm also running a single Solr node with 'cassandra -s' on localhost.

Comment: The 'undefined field realtime' result comes with this exception in the log https://gist.github.com/wagerlabs/026b9c590e1cee770e3d

Comment: There are no fields named 'realtime' but that is a key in 3 fields: https://gist.github.com/wagerlabs/42587cbd5252b89f8223 I think this may be the source of all the trouble.

Comment: What happens when you set those keys to null?

Comment: You should set this in your solrconfig.xml and reload the core <dseTypeMappingVersion>2</dseTypeMappingVersion>

Comment: Also is this the dev or prod environment?  Your KS RF shows 3 solr nodes for prod but you said you had only one solr node

Comment: What is KS RF? Keyspace ... ?

Comment: phact I don't think I can set those fields to null. There's some concatenation magic that happens somewhere.

Comment: Alright, I'll fix the KS RF as well as the type mapping version.

Comment: I dropped the KS and reloaded the CQL schema with 1 Solr and 1 Cassandra node. I restarted the node. I set dseTypeMappingVersion to 2. There was even one moment where I fetched two content_ids via Solr. That was with nothihg in Cassandra and went away after a reindex, though. I'm back to the realtime error before a full reindex and no data after.

Comment: Here's the log file that shows the exception before full reindex and no exception after. https://gist.github.com/wagerlabs/f34da60f1be680c15a5b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using Dynamic Fields to query Maps in Cassandra, you must begin the Key in your Map with the prefixed map literal. In your case the prefixed map literals are :

score_calculated_

score_value_

score_velocity_

shared_on_

The reason the error 'undefined field realtime' is coming is because realtime is not prefixed by the prefix specified for that field in schema.xml.

An example of what one of your records would look like would be:

{'score_value_realtime': 18.432}

Do the same for all the map values.

For more details see this url:
http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/3.2/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchDynFlds.html